# les gilets jaunes - die Gelbwesten

Tags: noun

Ein paar Tage lang waren *les gilets jaunes* in den deutschen Medien die *gilets jaunes*, dann wurden daraus *die Gelbwesten*, nach dem gleichen Wortbildungsmuster wie *Blauhelme, Blauhemden, Braunhemden* oder *Weißkittel* beispielsweise.

Als die Polizeiuniformen noch grün waren, konnte man von den *grünen Männchen* sprechen - 'Grünmännchen', 'Grünmänner', 'Grünuniformen', 'Grünuniformierte' oder 'Grünuniformisten' gab es nicht, obwohl sich diese Wörter bilden lassen. Für die *boys in blue* gibt es auf Deutsch eine Reihe von Wörtern, aber keines, das mit *blau-* beginnt, obwohl die Polizeiuniformen inzwischen blau sind. Müllmänner sind die *Männer in Orange*, nicht die 'Orange-Männer'; der *schwarze Block* ist der schwarze Block, nicht der 'Schwarzblock'.

Erkennt jemand ein Distributionsmuster? Wenn ja, welches?

Comment: Ohne weiteren Kontext sind "grüne Männchen" für mich Marsbewohner - es muss da mal einen fantastischen Stoff gegeben haben, in dem das so war. Polizisten sind ja weder klein, noch werden sie oft als klein erlebt, so dass "Männchen" oft unangemessen ist. Zudem sind viele Uniformen der Bundeswehr ebenfalls grün, so dass der Begriff nicht zur Abgrenzung taugt. Blaumann ist schon in Gebrauch für die Handwerkeranzüge.

Comment: **Grüne Männchen:** 1898 schrieb H. G. Wells den Science-Fiction Roman »The War of the Worlds«. 1907 veröffentlichte Wells dann im *Cosmopolitan Magazine* den Artikel »The Things that Live on Mars« und der Maler William Robinson Leigh wurde vom Verlag beauftragt, die Geschichte zu illustrieren. Dabei malte Leigh die Marsianer mit großen Köpfen aus denen Antennen wuchsen, und mit grüner Hautfarbe. Die Marsianer späterer Science-Fiction-Illustratoren waren alle von Leighs Vorlage beinflusst, und auch die Autoren von SF-Geschichten gingen danach dazu über, von grünen Männchen zu schreiben.

Comment: **Blaumann:** Ein Blaumann ist keine Person. Ein Blaumann ist ein Kleidungsstück, nämlich ein blauer Overall, der als Berufsbekleidung von Handwerkern getragen wird.

Comment: Als Deutscher, der gerade in Frankreich lebt, muss ich ja sagen, dass ich die Übersetzung "Die Gelben Westen" besser fände...

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Ich habe kein tieferes Wissen hier, aber ich bin skeptisch gegenüber der Leigh-Geschichte; und zwar einfach dahingehend, dass ich vermuten würde, dass sich in der Literatur- und Illustrationsgeschichte durchaus früher schon grüne Monstermännchen finden lassen, die Leigh wieder beeinflusst haben werden. Was ist mit mittelalterlichen Handschriftenillumnationen? - Schneller Blick durch eine Sammlung zeigt, dass Grün zwar selten ist (vor allem Drachen werden grün gemalt), aber es gibt auch grüne Männchen und Teufelchen. - Kurz: Es gab schon eine Literatur vor den Amerikanern.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Alles was du sagst ist richtig, aber es ging ja um die Frage, wie »grüne Männchen« zum Synonym für »Marsmenschen« wurde. Marsianer wirst du in mittelalterlichen Sammlungen kaum finden, und wenn doch, erlangten sie damals nicht in genügend große Teile der Bevölkerung, um den Begriff »grüne Männchen« als Synonym für Marschmenschen zu etablieren.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Ich glaube, deine These, dass Marsianer in mittelalterlichen illustrierten Handschriften nicht zu finden seien, ist zu forsch. Es sind definitv grüne Männchen zu finden, oft mit sehr unirdischen Körperformen (teils gar mit antennenartigen Fortsätzen auf dem Kopf). Ich würde wetten (den Beweis muss ich noch schuldig bleiben), dass auch dreibeinige Wesen und solche mit Tentakeln dabei sind. Wie wolltest du da sicher sein, dass das keine Marsmenschen sind? Die populäre Deutung, es seien Teufel oder Dämonen, ist ja offensichtlicher Unfug: Es gibt keine Teufel und Dämonen!

Comment: *»Die populäre Deutung, es seien Teufel oder Dämonen, ist ja offensichtlicher Unfug: Es gibt keine Teufel und Dämonen!«* Aber Marsmenschen gibt es? Oder wie? Im Mittelalter hatte die Kirche das Sagen, und im Mittelalter haben die Katholiken die Hölle, die ja in der Bibel nirgendwo näher beschrieben wird, mit allerlei garstigen Gesellen angefüllt, die mit ihrer Schaurigkeit die Fantasie der Menschen anregten. Im Mittelalter war es auch unvorstellbar darüber nachzudenken, dass der Schöpfer außer der Erde noch eine andere Welt erschaffen haben könnte, wenn doch davon nichts in der Bibel steht.

Answer (score 2):

> Erkennt jemand ein Distributionsmuster? Wenn ja, welches?

Genau so wie bei der Frage, welches Genus ein neues Fremdwort in der deutschen Sprache bekommt, gehe ich davon aus, dass es hier keine echte Logik gibt.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass derartige Begriffe einfach von den Menschen (und den Medien) verwendet werden, und der meistverwerwendete Begriff sich durchsetzt.

Möglicherweise hat die "Hintertupfinger Tagespost" geschrieben, dass "die Gelben Westen" in Paris randaliert haben, und der "Kleinkleckersdorfer Anzeiger" hat von "den Westen in Gelb" berichtet.

Aber die Tagesschau hat gemeldet, dass es "die Gelbwesten" waren. Und die hat nun mal deutlich mehr Zuschauer als die beiden Zeitungen zusammengenommen jemals an Lesern haben werden. Deswegen hat sich der Begriff "die Gelbwesten" und nicht "die Gelben Westen" und auch nicht der Begriff "die Westen in Gelb" durchgesetzt.

Answer (score 1):

Es scheint nur dann eine Verkürzung zum Kompositum geben, wenn die Farbe echt (also z.B. nicht Orange) und das Hauptwort ein Kleidungsstück ist. Es gibt auch noch die "Rotröcke" und die "gelben Engel". "Uniform" scheint eine Ausnahme, weil das Wort sich im eigentlichen Sinn nicht auf ein Kleidungsstück bezieht, sondern die Tatsache bezieht, das alle (sichtbaren) Kleidungsstücke gleich sind.

Comment: Meinst Du mit _echt_ in "wenn die Farbe echt [...] ist" die [Grundfarben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundfarbe/Allgemein) Rot, Gelb und Blau?

Comment: Grün, Grau, Weiß, Schwarz gehören auch noch dazu. Bei Gelb scheint es ein Grenzfall zu sein. Es gibt keine "Gelbmeise", sondern eine "Kohlmeise".

Comment: @Janka das liegt daran, dass es keine gelben Meisen gibt - blaue und schwarze schon. Es gibt z.B. *Gelbfüssler*, das sind für die Schwaben die Badener, und meine Oma sprach von den Nazis hinter vorgehaltener Hand von *Gelhemader"

Comment: @tofro Kannst du *gelhernader* bitte erläutern?

Comment: @Philipp "Gelbhemden"

Comment: @Marzipanherz Mit echteb Farben meine ich die deklinierbaren Farbadjektive (rot, weiß, grün, ...).

Comment: @tofro  Interessant, dass sie das Gel (also Gelb) nennt. Welche Farbe (nach heutigen deutschen Farbnamenssystem) hatten diese Hemden? Beige?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Kanariengelb waren sie natürlich nicht. Ein heutiger Designer würde die Farbe wohl als "Sand" anpreisen. Das liegt daran, dass sich die SA bei ihrer Gründung von der Resterampe bediente und Uniformhemden kaufte, die ursprünglich für die Schutztruppe von Deutsch-Südwest gedacht und nach dessen Verlust wohl billig zu haben waren. Farbe also irgendwo zwischen "ockergelb" und "kälberdreckbraun"

Comment: Oh weia! Wo sind wir gelandet, wenn eine in der Linguistik alltägliche Frage, nämlich die nach der Distribution von was auch immer, als "too broad" diskreditiert wird? Und was sagt diese Diskreditierung über diejenigen, die sie vornehmen?  -  Da guidot, Philipp, Björn Friedrich, Hubert Schölnast und Jan es nicht gemerkt haben: das *narrowing-down* ist in der Frage bereits enthalten. Ach ja, lesen müsste man können, und etwas von der Materie verstehen.  -  Dank an Toscho und user unknown für die durchdachten und überlegenswerten Ansätze. **Só** kommt man einer Antwort näher.

Answer (score -2):

Weste, Helm, Hemd, Kittel sind alles kurze Wörter von 1-2 Silben, so dass Wortbildungen mit Farbnamen nicht unhandlich lang werden.

Uniformen dagegen hat schon 4 Silben, das könnte zu umständlich sein. Grün ist aber eben bei der Polizei nicht nur das Hemd gewesen, sondern auch die Hosen und Teile der Mütze.

Beim schwarzen Block ist meist die gesamte Kleidung schwarz, vom Schuh über die Socken bis zur Sturmmaske. Da die anderen Bildungen alle für einzelne Personen gelten (der Blauhelm, ein Weißkittel) oder gelten können müsste die Analogbildung beim schwarzen Block auch lauten Schwarzblöckler. Dafür haben sich aber die kürzeren Formen *Autonomer* bzw. *Chaot* schon eingebürgert.